# Filtering data causing an error called "Pasring error: Unexpected Token"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

This is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/filter-sr3ci?file=/src/App.js:24-1548

I have these JSON data and I'm trying to filter all of the values of others and at the same time count them. Example:

One of the values of others in `"1"` is book:

```
{
      displayName: "Person3",
      "1": { others: "book", items1: { car: true, bike: true } },
      "2": {
        others: "",
        items2: { bike: true, motor: true, truck: true }
      }
    },

    {
      displayName: "Person4",
      "1": { others: "book", items1: { car: true, bike: true } },
      "2": { others: "", items2: { truck: true, bike: true } }
    },
```

I wanted to display in the screen something like this:

```
"1" data:
Book - 2
```

It goes the same with "2" which has the values of fan and and wire:

```
"2" data:
fan - 3
wire - 2
```

I tried filtering it but it has a red line in this code and has an error that says "Parsing Error":

```
const others1  = data.filter((d) => d."1"?.others !== "")
```

Below are the codes:

```
export default function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      displayName: "Person1",
      "1": { others: "", items1: { car: true, motor: true } }
    },
    {
      displayName: "Person2",
      "1": {
        others: "",
        items1: { car: true, motor: true, bike: true }
      },
      "2": { items2: { truck: true, bike: true }, others: "wire" }
    },

    {
      displayName: "Person3",
      "1": { others: "book", items1: { car: true, bike: true } },
      "2": {
        others: "wire",
        items2: { bike: true, motor: true, truck: true }
      }
    },

    {
      displayName: "Person4",
      "1": { others: "book", items1: { car: true, bike: true } },
      "2": { others: "", items2: { truck: true, bike: true } }
    },
    {
      displayName: "Person5",
      "1": { others: "", items1: { motor: true, car: true } },
      "2": {
        items2: { truck: true, bike: true },
        others: "fan"
      }
    },
    {
      displayName: "Person6",
      "2": {
        items2: { car: true, truck: true, motor: true },
        others: "fan"
      }
    },
    {
      "1": { others: "book", items1: { motor: true, car: true } },
      "2": {
        items2: { car: true, truck: true },
        others: "fan"
      },

      displayName: "Person7"
    }
  ];

  const others1  = data.filter((d) => d."1"?.others !== "")
  // console.log(others1.length);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: should be `data.filter((d) => d["1"].?others !== "")`

Comment: Why aren't you using arrays instead of objects with number keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you want to access an object with a number key, use [Index Property Accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)**

```js
const person = {
  1: 'John',
  2: 'Doe'
};

console.log(person['1']);
```

**So change to something like this:**

```
const others1  = data.filter((d) => d["1"]?.others !== "")
```

Comment: How can I also display and count the `others`? Since this `others` are taken from what the user has entered which may be different each time

Comment: You then need to store your `others` into a state, updating that state every time users change it. To count, an [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function would help.

Comment: I've tried this but it says "cannot read property "others" of undefined  `let red = [...others1].reduce(
    (a, c) => (
      (a[c.["1"]?.others] = (a[c.["1"].others] || 0) + 1), a
    ),
    {}
  );`

Comment: This is a bit out of context of this question, would you be so kind to post another question for that specific concern?

Comment: Thank you. I posed it already with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69127214/using-reduce-and-it-caused-an-error-that-says-cannot-read-property-others-of