# Using reduce and it caused an error that says "Cannot read property 'others' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I'm using a reduce on this and it has an error that says: ""Cannot read property 'others' of undefined"

This is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/filter-sr3ci?file=/src/App.js:1408-1536

```
 let red = [...others1].reduce(
    (a, c) => (
      (a[c.["1"]?.others] = (a[c.["1"].others] || 0) + 1), a
    ),
    {}
  );
```

Below are the codes:
import "./styles.css";

```
export default function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      displayName: "Person1",
      "1": { others: "", items1: { car: true, motor: true } }
    },
    {
      displayName: "Person2",
      "1": {
        others: "",
        items1: { car: true, motor: true, bike: true }
      },
      "2": { items2: { truck: true, bike: true }, others: "wire" }
    },

    {
      displayName: "Person3",
      "1": { others: "book", items1: { car: true, bike: true } },
      "2": {
        others: "wire",
        items2: { bike: true, motor: true, truck: true }
      }
    },

    {
      displayName: "Person4",
      "1": { others: "book", items1: { car: true, bike: true } },
      "2": { others: "", items2: { truck: true, bike: true } }
    },
    {
      displayName: "Person5",
      "1": { others: "", items1: { motor: true, car: true } },
      "2": {
        items2: { truck: true, bike: true },
        others: "fan"
      }
    },
    {
      displayName: "Person6",
      "2": {
        items2: { car: true, truck: true, motor: true },
        others: "fan"
      }
    },
    {
      "1": { others: "book", items1: { motor: true, car: true } },
      "2": {
        items2: { car: true, truck: true },
        others: "fan"
      },

      displayName: "Person7"
    }
  ];

  const others1 = data.filter((d) => d["1"]?.others !== "");

  // console.log(others1.length);

  let red = [...others1].reduce(
    (a, c) => (
      (a[c.["1"]?.others] = (a[c.["1"].others] || 0) + 1), a
    ),
    {}
  );


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: `a[c["1"].others]` should be `a[c["1"]?.others]` But what are you trying to achieve with `(a[c["1"]?.others] = (a[c["1"].others] || 0) + 1), a;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's because the object with the display name `Person6` doesn't have a "1" object**

When the `Array.reduce` function goes item by item, it could not find the `"1"` result in an undefined error.

So you just need to use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) for it like so:

```
let red = others1.reduce(
  (a, c) => ((a[c["1"]?.others] = (a[c["1"]?.others] || 0) + 1), a),
  {}
);
```

Also, remove those dots before `.["1"]`, since they are not valid, `['value']` is already equal to `.value`