# What's causing the undefined here and how can I somehow remove it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have already filtered and reduced the data. Then, I could also display it in the screen. I just want to know, what's causing the `undefined` here and how can I remove it or how can I not make it invisible on the screen?

This is also in the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/filter-sr3ci?file=/src/App.js:0-2255

This is what it shows in the screen:
[image]

```
export default function App() {
  const data = [
    {
      displayName: "Person1",
      "1": { others: "novella", items1: { car: true, motor: true } }
    },
    {
      displayName: "Person2",
      "1": {
        others: "novella",
        items1: { car: true, motor: true, bike: true }
      },
      "2": { items2: { truck: true, bike: true }, others: "wire" }
    },

    {
      displayName: "Person3",
      "1": { others: "book", items1: { car: true, bike: true } },
      "2": {
        others: "wire",
        items2: { bike: true, motor: true, truck: true }
      }
    },

    {
      displayName: "Person4",
      "1": { others: "book", items1: { car: true, bike: true } },
      "2": { others: "", items2: { truck: true, bike: true } }
    },
    {
      displayName: "Person5",
      "1": { others: "novella", items1: { motor: true, car: true } },
      "2": {
        items2: { truck: true, bike: true },
        others: "fan"
      }
    },
    {
      displayName: "Person6",
      "2": {
        items2: { car: true, truck: true, motor: true },
        others: "fan"
      }
    },
    {
      "1": { others: "book", items1: { motor: true, car: true } },
      "2": {
        items2: { car: true, truck: true },
        others: "fan"
      },

      displayName: "Person7"
    }
  ];

  const others1 = data.filter((d) => d["1"]?.others !== "");
  const others2 = data.filter((d) => d["2"]?.others !== "");

  let red = others1.reduce(
    (a, c) => ((a[c["1"]?.others] = (a[c["1"]?.others] || 0) + 1), a),
    {}
  );

  let red2 = others2.reduce(
    (a, c) => ((a[c["2"]?.others] = (a[c["2"]?.others] || 0) + 1), a),
    {}
  );

  // let ar = [];
  // let json = "";
  // for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(red)) {
  //   console.log(key, value);
  //   ar.push(key, value);

  //   json = JSON.stringify(ar);
  // }

  function objToString(obj) {
    let str = "";
    for (const [p, val] of Object.entries(red)) {
      str += `${p}:${val}\n`;
    }
    return str;
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {/* {json} */}
      {objToString()}
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are asking every step of your homework [Previous step question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69127214/using-reduce-and-it-caused-an-error-that-says-cannot-read-property-others-of)

Comment: Is there a reason that you're using objects with numbered keys instead of arrays. An array would make your life much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to answer your problem you can simply do this to solve your problem.
Note that p is an object key which is somehow coming to be "undefined" here. So you need to check it for string "undefined".
Your actual problem should be why an undefined key is being set

```
     if (p !== "undefined") {
        str += `${p}:${val}\n`;
      }
```